# Format json variables for POST to lambda

Tags: node.js, json, post, aws-lambda, lambda

I'm trying to POST "body":"Test" and "subject":"Test" to a Lambda function through AWS REST API Gateway, which will use this to send an email using AWS SES.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'eu-west-2' });
exports.handler = (event) => {
    sendMail(event);
};

async function sendMail(event) {
    const emailParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["**EMAIL**"],
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: { Data: event.body },
            },
            Subject: { Data: event.subject },
        },
        Source: "**ANOTHEREMAIL**",
    };

    try {
        let response = await ses.sendEmail(emailParams).promise();
        console.log("MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY!!");
        console.log("subject:", event.subject);
        console.log("body:", event.body);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        return response;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("FAILURE IN SENDING MAIL!!", e);
        console.log("subject:", event.subject);
        console.log("body:", event.body);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    }
    return;
}
```

The above works beautifully using the lambda Test event function in AWS using the json:

```
{
  "subject": "Testing",
  "body": "Testing"
}
```

However when I try to POST the same json using postman I get:

```
subject: undefined
body: { "subject":"Testing", "body":"Testing" }
```

I can see the data being passed with AWS built-in tester is formatted as:

```
 {"subject":"New Test","body":"New test body"}
```

However, with postMan it's:

```
{
    "resource": "/contact",
    "path": "/contact",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Host": "REDACTED",
        "Postman-Token": "REDACTED",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64d629d1-6991407c4ca2e1125b6d1858",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "REDACTED",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "multiValueHeaders": {
        "Accept": [
            "*/*"
        ],
        "Accept-Encoding": [
            "gzip, deflate, br"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/json"
        ],
        "Host": [
            "REDACTED"
        ],
        "Postman-Token": [
            "REDACTED"
        ],
        "User-Agent": [
            "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3"
        ],
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
            "REDACTED"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-For": [
            "REDACTED"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Port": [
            "443"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
            "https"
        ]
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": null,
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
        "resourceId": "wsryph",
        "resourcePath": "/contact",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "extendedRequestId": "Jft41HVGLPEFUTg=",
        "requestTime": "11/Aug/2023:12:30:09 +0000",
        "path": "/Test/contact",
        "accountId": "REDACTED",
        "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
        "stage": "Test",
        "domainPrefix": "REDACTED",
        "requestTimeEpoch": 1691757009857,
        "requestId": "REDACTED",
        "identity": {
            "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
            "accountId": null,
            "cognitoIdentityId": null,
            "caller": null,
            "sourceIp": "REDACTED",
            "principalOrgId": null,
            "accessKey": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
            "userArn": null,
            "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3",
            "user": null
        },
        "domainName": "REDACTED",
        "apiId": "717s3x0a01"
    },
    "body": "{ \r\n    \"body\":\"Test\",\r\n    \"subject\":\"test\"\r\n}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Can someone point out the very simple mistake I've made? This is my first ever project using API gateways, lambdas, Node.js and json so I know there are probably a million ways to improve the above so please let me know as I want to learn!

UPDATE:
new working lambda code:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'eu-west-2' });
exports.handler = (event) => {
    sendMail(event);
};

async function sendMail(param) {
    let email = JSON.parse(param.body);
    const emailParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["EMAIL"],
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: { Data: email.body },
            },
            Subject: { Data: email.subject },
        },
        Source: "EMAIL",
    };

    try {
        let response = await ses.sendEmail(emailParams).promise();
        console.log("MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY!!");
        console.log("subject:", email.subject);
        console.log("body:", email.body);
        console.log(param);
        return response;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("FAILURE IN SENDING MAIL!!", e);
        console.log("subject:", email.subject);
        console.log("body:", email.body);
        console.log(param);
    }
    return;
}
```

Working AWS test:

```
{
  "body": {
    "subject": "New Test",
    "body": "New test body"
  }
}
```

POSTMAN TEST:

```
{
    "subject": "Testing",
    "body": "Testing"
}
```

Adding JSON.parse(param.body) fixed the final issue!

Comment: Does it print any error message in the console(Cloudwatch logs)?

Comment: All errors relate to the subject variable missing data, as both parsed parameters are being assigned to the body var. no other errors. It must be related to paring the data in the body tag in Postman, but can't figure out how to test it otherwise.

Comment: This is working as expected. The `event` object from API Gateway has this format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event You made the mistake of thinking the `event` object is just going to be a copy of the data you sent to the POST request and nothing else. Your test event does not accurately test your code against an API Gateway event object.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the information! I've updated my lambda code to account for this, however still seeing issues.

Comment: You need to call `JSON.parse()` on the `event.body` value, as it just comes in as a string, since there is no guarantee you sent a JSON value to the API.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you that was the final piece of the puzzle! now works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are sending the data as a JSON. In Postman, try sending using raw JSON method.

Then enter the value:

```
{
  "subject": "Testing",
  "body": "Testing"
}
```

Also update your lambda code to get the body parameter from the event payload:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'eu-west-2' });
exports.handler = (event) => {
    sendMail(event);
};

async function sendMail(param) {

let event = JSON.parse(param.body);
    const emailParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["**EMAIL**"],
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: { Data: event.body },
            },
            Subject: { Data: event.subject },
        },
        Source: "**ANOTHEREMAIL**",
    };

    try {
        let response = await ses.sendEmail(emailParams).promise();
        console.log("MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY!!");
        console.log("subject:", event.subject);
        console.log("body:", event.body);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        return response;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("FAILURE IN SENDING MAIL!!", e);
        console.log("subject:", event.subject);
        console.log("body:", event.body);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I have tested that, and when I log the values set for body, and subject. I get "body":"{ "subject": "Testing", "body": "Testing" }" and "Subject":undefined

Comment: @chyke007  you are missing that API Gateway is being used, and it is sending a full API Gateway event object to the Lambda function.

Comment: Does it work now? Also @Mark, the event params has a body property that includes the payload sent, he wasn't taking this into account

Comment: @chyke007 I think I'm closer but still isn't working. console.log(JSON.stringify(event)). returns "{\r\n \"subject\": \"Testing\",\r\n \"body\": \"Testing\"\r\n}"

Comment: Any reason why you are stringifying the event? Can you parse the event instead

Comment: @chyke007 just noticed POSTMAN is parsing the whole body as a string and AWS isn't? however I selected raw json